# How do I achieve this Image in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

am having challenge in achieving the attached image, can someone help me out.
I tried UIView with UIBezierPath but am not getting the result. Please help.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: check this controller may be it'l helps you.https://github.com/tiagomnh/THCircularProgressView

Comment: @Ben I created a view and an also a UIBezierPath to achieve that, but the result is so ambigious

Comment: @Sunny that's for load progress view, kind useful. I trying to look into the source code and make it non animated. thanks

Comment: you can set progress value then it won't animate.

Comment: @Sunny I have achieved the result, thanks to u all. you guyz're great! U can paste ur comment as an answer....get ur reward man!